# Possible chief factors of a group of order 336

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups, direct-product

Determine, up to isomorphism, the possible chief factors of a group of order $336$.

I have answered this but would like to know if I am right or have missed anything?

So I know the possible chief factors are the possible characteristically simple groups whose order divides $336$. These are either simple or direct products of isomorphic simple groups.

The only non-abelian simple group whose order divides $336$ is a group, call it $H$ whose order is $168$. Then we are left with groups of prime order for primes dividing $336$, giving $C_2$, $C_3$ and $C_7$.

We can also take direct products of copies of these simple groups, as long as the order of the direct product still divides $336$. So does that leave us with the only possible chief factors as

$H$,

$C_2$,

$C_2\times C_2$,

$C_2\times C_2\times C_2$,

$C_2\times C_2\times C_2\times C_2$,

$C_3$,

$C_7$.

Comment: What's missing is a check whethre all these candiategroups actually *do* occur as chief factors in a suitable chief series for a suitable group (I have some doubts about $C_2^4$, for example)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, your doubts are surely well founded; there's no way either the cyclic group of order $21$ or the Frobenius group of order $21$ can act irreducibly on $V_4(F_2)$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, I don't follow - which of these on my list has order $21$?

Comment: If $(C_2)^{4}$ is to be a chief factor it's going to have to be irreducible under the action of a group of order $3$ or $7$ or $21$. None of these is possible.

Comment: So $C_2^4$ cannot occur as a chief factor. All of the others on the list can occur, but that still has to be proved. It's easy for the cyclic groups. $C_2^2$ arises as a chief factor of $A_4 \times C_{28}$. For $C_2^3$ you could take $F_{56} \times C_6$, where $F_{56}$ is a Frobenius group of order $56$.