# Finding possible lengths of a chief series

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, simple-groups

Suppose $G$ is a group with a chief series $G = G_0 ≥ G_1 ≥ · · · ≥ G_r = {1}$. If
$|G| = 336$, how could I find what all the possible values of $r$ are?

(Note that $H$ is the only non-abelian simple group whose order divides 336)

I now know $r$ cannot equal $1$, due to $H$. But it can equal $2$ and $6$ however, I don't know how to determine if it could be $3$, $4$ or $5$, I have tried by eye to see if I can create a series of these lengths and haven't managed to find one, I wondered if there was a better way?

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211575/possible-chief-factors-of-a-group-of-order-336) for previous information that may help with this question.

Comment: $336 = 2^4 \times 3 \times 7$

Comment: I know that.. but how does that help?

Comment: It means that the "one possibility" that you wrote doesn't make sense. If $H$ is simple then it cannot have $C_2^3$ as a normal subgroup can it? The nonabelian simple group in question has order $168$. So $r=1$ is not possible, but $r=2$ is a possibility, and so is $r=6$ coming from the cyclic group. So it remains to determine which of $r=3,4,5$ are possible. I haven't thought about that yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $r=2$ there is the example $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \text{GL}(3,2)$.

For $r=4$ there is the example $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_3\times \text{Frob}_{56}$ where 
$$ \text{Frob}_{56}=\left\{\left[\begin{matrix}\zeta^j & 0\\a & \zeta^{-j}\end{matrix}\right]: a\in\mathbb{F}_8, \zeta\ \text{a generator of}\ \mathbb{F}^{*}_8 \right\}.$$

For $r=5$ there is the example $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_7\times\text{A}_4$.

For $r=6$ there is the example $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3
\times\mathbb{Z}_7$.

But, $r=1$ is not possible since there is no simple group of order $336$.

And $r=3$ is not possible since the chief factors would have to be $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^4$, $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $\mathbb{Z_7}$; which would force the $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^4$ to be normal, and then there is no irreducible action of either of the groups of order $21$ on a $4$-dimensional space over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: Thank you, I thought when $r=4$, there had to be four composition factors i.e $G/G_1, G_1/G_2, G_2/G_3$ and $G_3/\{1\}$? I'm struggling to understand why in your example for $r=4$ there are only three?

Comment: The Frobenius group has two of the chief factors, a $\mathbb{Z}_7$ and an elementary abelian group of order $8$.

Comment: Thank you, one last thing, why is $A_4$ a chief factor if it is not simple?

Comment: Same story, it provides two of the chief factors, a $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and an elementary group of order $4$.

Comment: So this elementary abelian group of order $4$, would it be isomporphic to the group $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$? As this is the only group on my list of possible chief factors that has order $4$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. And the one of order $8$ earlier is the product of three $\mathbb{Z}_2$'s.